# Custom validation error message based on regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, error-handling, ruby-on-rails-5

I made a custom validation for password field in my application using regex and format helper. It is working properly.

I want to add a **custom error message** for that validation.

I tried adding message validator and used locales for the same. But none of them seem to help me.

Original validation:

`has_secure_password
VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX = /\A(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W])(?=.*[\d])[\S]{8,15}\z/
validates :password, format: { with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }, allow_nil: true`

When message validator is used:

`has_secure_password
VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX = /\A(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W])(?=.*[\d])[\S]{8,15}\z/
validates :password, format: { with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }, allow_nil: true,
    message: ' should contain uppercase, lowercase, number and special character. Between 8 and 15 characters long'`

The error message shown was: `Unknown validator: 'MessageValidator'`

The same error showed up when I wrote `:message => "Error message"` instead of the  `message: "Error message"`

Wrote the original validation when locales were used.
en.yml file was changed to:

`en:
  activemodel:
    attributes:
      employee:
        password: "Password"
    errors:
      models:
        employee:
          attributes:
            password: "should contain at least one uppercase, lowercase, numeric and special character. Between 8 and 15 characters long"`

The application works properly without any error messages. But when invalid password was entered, the error message shown was

- Password is invalid

PS: For showing error messages in the view(application.html.erb), I have used:

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place the `message` key within `format` otherwise it thinks you're trying to apply a `MessageValidator`

```
validates :password, format: { 
                       with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX, 
                       message: 'should contain uppercase, lowercase, number and special character. Between 8 and 15 characters long' 
                     }, 
                     allow_nil: true
```